# Php email - inline image and 2 attachments

Tags: php

I've been struggling with this script for 5 days now and I just can't get it to work. I want to send a mail using php mail function. It needs to have an inline image, and 2 attachments. What I've got does that, and it displays correcty in Thunderbird, but in Gmail client it shows the image as attachment, and not in the body of the message. Here's the code that I have:

```
<?php

$filename = "sharewood-lija-cjenik.xlsx";
$filename2 = "sharewood-lija-ponuda.pdf";
$inline = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents('../img/sharewoodlija.png')));
$sep = sha1(date('r', time()));

$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));

$subject = "Sharewood Lija";
$mailto = "mymail@gmail.com";

$message = '<img src="cid:image_identifier" alt="SWLBanner" /><br><br>';
$message .="<div>html message</div>";

$header = "From: asdf <asdf@asdf.hr>\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: asdf@asdf.hr\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";

$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";  

$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";    
$header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=uft-8\r\n";
//$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";

//image
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: image/png;\r\n";
$header .= "name=\"sharewoodlija.png\"\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-ID: <image_identifier>\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: inline;\r\n";
$header .= "filename=\"sharewoodlija.png\"\r\n\r\n";

$header .= $inline."\r\n";

//cjenik
$file = "../cjenik/sharewood-lija-cjenik.xlsx";
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));  
$name = basename($file);

$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";

//ponuda
$file2 = "../cjenik/sharewood-lija-ponuda.pdf";
$file_size2 = filesize($file2);
$handle2 = fopen($file2, "r");
$content2 = fread($handle2, $file_size2);
fclose($handle2);
$content2 = chunk_split(base64_encode($content2));
$name2 = basename($file2);

$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename2."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename2."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content2."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";



if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
}
?>
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: stop using mail() for this (mail() is VERY limited), use one of the libraries (phpmailer,swiftitmailer)

Comment: No, I need this to work with mail().

Comment: then you are making a rod for your own back.

Comment: `"------=_NextPart_".$uid."\r\n"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your program.   Google mail will not allow images.  I have seen 3 surveys of mail clients and most will not handle images like thunderbird.   Some won't even indicate that there is an image or show the alt title or anything
.